# Silverlight. The order of triggers invocation

Tags: silverlight, events, xaml, eventtrigger

There is a Silverlight `UserControl` which got an `MouseLeftButtonUp` event. In xaml I add two triggers for this event. In which order Silverlight xaml-parser will parse and attach those triggers and can I be sure that trigger above will invoke first?

```
...
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
      <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">
         <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{StaticResource someCommand}"/>
         <AttachedBehaviors:SomeBehavior Parameter="Apple"/>
      </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
...
```

---

*UPDATE:* Found connected issue [In WPF, does the order of Triggers matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561178/in-wpf-does-the-order-of-triggers-matter) which says:

> WPF is processing triggers in declared order.

*Hope, Silverlight behave exactly that same.*

Comment: Why not just run your code and find out for yourself?

Comment: @ColinE Now it works as expected. But I've read articles about strange parser behavior (as soon as I'll find it - I'll update question with a link) and I want get experts thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if the order is defined I wouldn't do this. Add the order you want to the handler of the command.

```
void someCommand_Executed()
{
    DoFirstThing();
    DoSecondThing();
}
```

This kind of code will cause pain in the long run because the order is not easily enforced and you are creating a dependency between two methods.

Comment: Thanks for advice. But in my case first I want to do some changes in `ViewModel` (lets say - save data: `someCommand`) and then invoke some Behavior that will update `Layout` regarding changes that were made previously.

Comment: Don't. Bind the View to the ViewModel and that should take propagate changes in the ViewModel to the View automatically.

Comment: It's bound and works well. I've got specific case and it is not data presenting. Under  "Layout update" I mean changing View at all (I Load another control, hide couple of others etc.) and it is not depending on `ViewModel`.

Comment: If that is true, you are either not dependent on order or you can still use my solution