# ListBoxItem AlternationIndex Trigger overrides IsSelected Trigger

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a ListboxItem Style defined as:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style x:Key="VoidwalkerListBoxItem" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Border
                        Name="_itemContainer"
                        Padding="0"
                        BorderBrush="Transparent"
                        BorderThickness="1"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <!--
                            Is Selected Triggers
                        -->
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="_itemContainer" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource VoidwalkerBorderBrush}" />
                            <Setter TargetName="_itemContainer" Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                        </Trigger>

                        <!--
                            Is Mouse Over Triggers
                        -->
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="_itemContainer" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource VoidwalkerBorderBrush}" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <!--
                            Alternation Coloration Triggers
                        -->
                        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource VoidwalkerForegroundBrush}" />
                            <Setter TargetName="_itemContainer" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource VoidwalkerContextBrush}" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource VoidwalkerForegroundBrush}" />
                            <Setter TargetName="_itemContainer" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource VoidwalkerControlBrush}" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Essentially, what I'm trying to do is alternate the background colors of every other item, which works. Here's a picture:

[image]

However, the problem then arises when I want to color the selected item's background, in this case I chose Red for testing purposes, along with a gray border brush. Here is the result:

[image]

As you can see, I have selected "Item 009", but the background has not been changed to red. The only thing that has changed is the border color. If I disable the AlternationIndex trigger, the background is colored correctly. This leaves me to believe that for some reason, the AlternationIndex trigger is taking precedence over the IsSelected Trigger, or being fired after the IsSelected Trigger, thus I see no red background.

***My question is: how can I fix my implementation to circumvent this apparent override of the IsSelected trigger, coloring my background Red, while also keeping the desired AlternationIndex coloration?***

Answer (score 1):

Wait...I feel stupid. You know, never once did I consider that XAML may have a load/declaration order. The apparent problem is that the triggers are fired within the order in which they're declared. It makes sense. Anyway, an *embarrassingly simple* solution to my problem is as follows...just declare the AlternationIndex triggers first, then declare the IsSelected trigger last in the XAML. Example:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style x:Key="VoidwalkerListBoxItem" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Border
                        Name="_itemContainer"
                        Padding="0"
                        BorderBrush="Transparent"
                        BorderThickness="1"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <!--
                            Alternation Coloration Triggers
                        -->
                        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource VoidwalkerForegroundBrush}" />
                            <Setter TargetName="_itemContainer" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource VoidwalkerContextBrush}" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource VoidwalkerForegroundBrush}" />
                            <Setter TargetName="_itemContainer" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource VoidwalkerControlBrush}" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <!--
                            Is Selected Triggers
                        -->
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="_itemContainer" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource VoidwalkerBorderBrush}" />
                            <Setter TargetName="_itemContainer" Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                        </Trigger>

                        <!--
                            Is Mouse Over Triggers
                        -->
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="_itemContainer" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource VoidwalkerBorderBrush}" />
                        </Trigger>

                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

[image]