# Strange ColorAnimation and MultiTrigger behavior on ListView

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a listview. I want to implement this behavior:

1. The initial color of non-clicked item is *Gray*
2. When mouse is over **non-clicked** item item, the item changes from *Gray* to *Black*. When  mouse moves out, the item changes its color back to *Gray*
3. When item is clicked it changes to *Red*
4. When mouse is over the clicked item, the item remains *Red* anyway.

Below is how I try to implement it:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}" x:Key="PackageListViewItemStyle">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1,1" />

    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment,
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                                                AncestorLevel=1,
                                                                AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
                Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment,
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                                                AncestorLevel=1,
                                                                AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PackageListItemPrimaryForegroundColorBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Rectangle Margin="2"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                                Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"
                                StrokeDashArray="1 2"
                                StrokeThickness="1" />
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Border x:Name="Bd"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}"
                                ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <!-- mouse hovers -->
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False" />
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Name="glowsb">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Bd"
                                                    From="Gray" To="Black"
                                                    Duration="0:0:0.9"
                                                    AutoReverse="False"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"/>
                                </Storyboard>   
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                        </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Name="glowsbback">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Bd"
                                                    From="Black"
                                                    To="Gray"
                                                    Duration="0:0:0.9"
                                                    AutoReverse="False"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                        Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="Bd"
                        Property="TextElement.Foreground"
                        Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

As you can see the animation is used only for mouseOver/mouseLeave event.

Result: animation works as expected but when I click an item it becomes *Gray* instead of *Red*.

I figured that here *Gray* comes from *ExitAction Animation "To"* property.

If I change it like this:

```
<MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
 <BeginStoryboard Name="glowsbback">
  <Storyboard>
   <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Bd"
    From="Black" To="Green" Duration="0:0:0.9" AutoReverse="False"                                                        
    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"/>
  </Storyboard>
 </BeginStoryboard>
</MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
```

then the clicked item becomes *Green*.

Ok, let's get rid of the "To" property:

```
<MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
 <BeginStoryboard Name="glowsbback">
  <Storyboard>
   <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Bd"
    From="Black" Duration="0:0:0.9" AutoReverse="False"                                                        
    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"/>
  </Storyboard>
 </BeginStoryboard>
</MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
```

Cool, the clicked item becomes *Red* as expected, but it goes to Red **animated**, whereas I put it in **Setter** without animation:

```
<Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
    <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Background" Value="Red" />
    <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
</Trigger>
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont't know if this is the most elegant way to solve your problem.

In WPF `Triggers` are processed in the order they are declared.
See also [In WPF, does the order of Triggers matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561178/in-wpf-does-the-order-of-triggers-matter)

Therefore you can put your "IsSelected"-Trigger right after your `MultiTrigger` and stop that animation by using [`StopStoryboard`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.animation.stopstoryboard?view=netframework-4.7.2)

---

Result:

```
...
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <MultiTrigger>
        <!-- mouse hovers -->
        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False" />
            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard Name="glowsb">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Bd"
                            From="Gray" To="Black"
                            Duration="0:0:0.9"
                            AutoReverse="False"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
        <MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
            <BeginStoryboard Name="glowsbback">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Bd"
                            From="Black"
                            Duration="0:0:0.9"
                            AutoReverse="False"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
    </MultiTrigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
        <Trigger.EnterActions>
            <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="glowsbback" />
        </Trigger.EnterActions>
        <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
             Value="False">
        <Setter TargetName="Bd"
                Property="TextElement.Foreground"
                Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
...
```

Comment: It works! Thank you! But why _<Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">_ must go after _MultiTrigger_ and have _<Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="glowsbback" />
                            </Trigger.EnterActions>_ ?
Without both conditions it wouldn't work.